# Install Release and Debug iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, release

How do I go about installing release build of my app (either from the AppStore or release build Xcode) and then a debug version simultaneously without overwriting one another?

I want to be able to use the release version as is while developing updates along side it. This must be common practice but I can't figure it out!

Thanks,
Josh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is using a different bundle identifier for your debug version. Doing this, the app will be treated as a separate app from the system. You can set the bundle identifier under your target general configuration window.

[image]